# File is created but information wont save in it

Tags: c#

Ok, so I'm new to C# and don't know what I'm doing wrong.
At the top of the button click event I have this variable:

```
InformationDump infodump;
infodump = new InformationDump();
```

After that I have the rest of the code which is meant to path to the user desktop and save whatever is filled out in the textbox's into a separate window (part of the same program):

```
infodump.richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ", " + textBox2.Text + ", " +         textBox3.Text + ", " + textBox4.Text + ", " + comboBox1.SelectedItem;
string path =     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string filename = path + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss") + System.Environment.UserName + ".txt";
infodump.richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions or errors?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using InformationDump vs StreamWriter?

Comment: The file is created in the correct location, It has the unique name like it should.
The information from the text boxes go across to the "infodump" window.
That's as far as I get, once the information is carried across to infodump it should save which doesn't work. So i'm left with a blank text file.

Comment: Why do you need to use a RichTextBox to save the value of 3 TextBoxes?

Comment: I'll be using that same RichTextBox later on in the program to add more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating an instance of the form (InformationDump) then try to use the RichTextBox instance but the form then will not go through the standard loading and initialization process therefore as I reproduced, the file will be created but will be empty.

It is very interesting, but if you do repeated save it works!

```
infodump.richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
// zero bytes
infodump.richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
// works!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although I now have another problem.
The text file has this as well as what I want it to contain:
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17"

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree it's a silly idea but it's part of a qualification which requires me to do this.
I found out the problem, I was saving the file as a .RichText type instead of .PlainText
The .RichText was saving the formatting of the text which I didn't need.